# Red x crosshair on text in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi In the text component On scene appeared a red x crosshair And my text doesn't appear at all
Do you what it can be?[image]

Comment: interesting thing happens When I "Rename" my Text object on Button component nothing But when I changed  Text name on others buttons (ButtonTOP and ButtonRight) I receive NullReference Exception Seems like Text on Button has no reference to Button object

Comment: Okey I just deleted a "Text" object and added again It works

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a common starter mistake. Probably your related GameObject's RectTransform Anchor values are inversed.

This can be caused by many things but generally if you set Anchor minimum values higher than maximum values this situation happens. Please set your `anchorMin.x` value lower than `anchorMax.x` and `anchorMin.y` value lower than `anchorMax.y`

Comment: no its seems it is not anchors but thanks for response anyway